# Display one column data to two column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A

```
| SLNO | TYPENAME | TYPEMODE |
------------------------------
|    1 |  Act.Alw |        A |
|    2 |  Canteen |        D |
```

I want to display two column according to its typmode

using UNION ALL I get

```
| Addition | Deduction |
------------------------
| Act.Alw  |           |
|          |  Canteen  |
```

I want display like this. Addtion and Deduction are alias

```
| ADDITION | DEDUCTION |
------------------------
|  Act.Alw |   Canteen |
```

Comment: What should be output if the table contains more than one record of the same `typemode`?

Comment: Please be more precise, what happens when more rows are present in the table ? A typename = 'D' is always consecutive to a  typename = 'A' ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use a join instead of a union. But it would be helpful if you could explain a little bit more about what you are trying to accomplish and maybe post he sql query you are currently trying to run.

Comment: select typename as Addition,'' as Deduction from typemaster where typemode='A'
union all
select '' as Addition, typename as Deduction from typemaster where typemode='D' this is my query

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement for that. To group them you need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` function like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN typemode = 'A' 
             THEN typename ELSE NULL END) AS Addition
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN typemode = 'D' 
              THEN typename ELSE NULL END) AS Deduction
FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
| ADDITION | DEDUCTION |
------------------------
|  Act.Alw |   Canteen |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f11d2/4)

Comment: @aleroot - If we don't use Group_concat then we won't get [desired result what OP want](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f11d2/6).